# How to create context-sensitive hotkeys when no window is active?

Tags: windows, automation, windows-10, autohotkey, hotkeys

I want to create some hotkeys when no window is active:

[image]

But there's no statement like `#IfNoWinActive`, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always an active window (the one that will get input).

E.g. the Win+X Menu has no title but a hidden ahk_class (LauncherTipWnd). To detect it you have to add `DetectHiddenWindows, On` in your script:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
DetectHiddenWindows, On

#IfWinActive ahk_class LauncherTipWnd ; Win+X Menu

    F1:: Run notepad
    F2:: Send m ; starts the Device Manager
    
#IfWinActive
```

**EDIT:**

To get the title and ahk_class of the (hidden) active window, run this script and press F1 as soon as that window is active:

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force

DetectHiddenWindows, On

F1::
    WinGetTitle, ActiveTitle, A
    WinGetClass, ActiveClass, A
    MsgBox, ActiveTitle: %ActiveTitle%`nActiveClass: ahk_class %ActiveClass%
return

F2::
    WinSetTitle, A, , NewTitle
    WinGetTitle, ActiveTitle, A
    MsgBox, ActiveTitle: %ActiveTitle%
return

F3::
    WinGet, ActiveExe, ProcessName, A
    MsgBox, ProcessName: "%ActiveExe%"
return
```

Press Ctrl+C to copy the content of the MsgBox.

**EDIT2**:

In case the active window has no title and no ahk_class you can try this:

```
F1:: 
    WinGetTitle, ActiveTitle, A
    WinGetClass, ActiveClass, A
    If (ActiveTitle = "" && ActiveClass = "")
        Run notepad
    ; else If WinActive("WinTitle ahk_class WinClass", "WinText", "ExcludeTitlePart")
        ; do this
    else
        Send {F1}
Return
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, my case seems there's indeed no active window, please see the [recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPyH4.gif). And I'd like to create some hotkeys when `ahk_exe` becomes empty, the program is `QQMusic.exe`, do you know how to do that?

Comment: I tried adding `DetectHiddenWindows On`, however, it breaks my [current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEjo4.png), not sure why.

Comment: See EDIT in this answer. What do you see if you run the code?

Comment: Please see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CnUV.png).

Comment: And what do you see if you press F2 in the re-edited code?

Comment: Please see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVIOu.png).

Comment: Try EDIT2 in this answer.

Comment: A notepad is opened.

Comment: Thanks for the effort! But there're two side effects to the last approach: 1. kind of resource-intensive with the all-time looping; 2. if the interval is larger, `ActiveWindowWithoutTitleClass` won't be updated in time. Nonetheless, still a working solution.

Comment: _"There is always an active window (the one that will get input)."_ The active window can even have no `ahk_exe` and `ahk_pid`? Given `WinGet ActiveExe, ProcessName, A` and the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm#ProcessName), I assumed the value is _"blank"_ because _"there are no matching windows"_ for `A` i.e. no active window.

Comment: And the Win+X menu has `ahk_exe Explorer.EXE`, my "active window" really has nothing, it seems to me that `QQMusic.exe` lost focus, and no window received it.

Comment: OK, SetTimer isn't a very good idea in this case. Try the re-edited code in EDIT2.

Comment: Thanks, that's more like [my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUcK4.png) now. Could you please share your thoughts on [comment 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755242/how-to-create-context-sensitive-hotkeys-when-no-window-is-active/69757521?noredirect=1#comment123337457_69757521) and [comment 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69755242/how-to-create-context-sensitive-hotkeys-when-no-window-is-active/69757521?noredirect=1#comment123337541_69757521)? It's causing a lot of confusion for me.

Comment: What do you get if you press F3 in the  re-edited EDIT? DetectHiddenWindows musst be On.

Comment: Please see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0hqr.png).

Comment: I am not an expert. You could ask in the Windows Forum about that.

Comment: Thanks for the help along the way, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe the window that became active had elevated privileges, so Window Spy wasn't able to access its information. If you can still reproduce the problem, try to run Window Spy as admin and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

```
~Esc::
  WinGet A, PID, A

  if !A {
    MsgBox ;  put logic here
  }
  return
```